# Modify CSV file to add a digit character to a column

Tags: batch-file

I have a problem making a batch file.
This text is inside a file with name `export.dat` and I have no means to change the CSV field item from 5 to 6 digits.
This is a preferred older program.
As for newer program I can add the required.

> ```
> D,1,2126,4372,T,125P,,255473730,person,n,person,19800320,07833,300.00,07833,300.00,078330
> ```

Has to be after modification:

> ```
> D,1,2126,4372,T,125P,,255473730,person,n,person,19800320,078330,300.00,078330 - A03.1 - Shigellosis d,,etc
> ```

So we have a leading capital `D` followed by 13 commas and batch should ad a zero before the comma 13.

Comment: Your question body does not match the before and after examples your posted. You said it should add "a zero before the comma 13". However what you appear to have done is to add a zero before the thirteenth comma and replace the fifteenth comma with `0 - A03.1 - Shigellosis d,,` BTW, Excel is irrelevant, `.csv` files may be importable and exportable with Excel, but it's files are generally those carrying an `.xls`, or `.xlsx` extension. A CSV is a plain text file with comma separated values, as is your provided example.

Comment: Can I for instance edit/replace or just replace with echo off  07833 to 078330   ?

Comment: No, you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "target=.\export.dat"
set "destination=.\updated.dat"

powershell -noprofile -command^
 "$content = get-content -literalpath '%target%';"^
 "$modifiedContent = @();"^
 "$modifiedContent += $content[0];"^
 "ForEach ($line in $content[1 .. ($content.count - 1)]) {"^
 " if ($line.startswith('D,')) {"^
 "  $items = $line.split(',');"^
 "  if ($items.length -gt 14) {$items[14] += '0'; $line = $items -join ','};"^
 " };"^
 " $modifiedContent += $line"^
 "};"^
 "$modifiedContent | set-content -literalpath '%destination%'"
```

Powershell has `Import-CSV` and `Export-CSV` which can handle CSV files, though `Export-CSV` outputs data with double quoted field items. Powershell 7 introduces arguments for quotes for `Export-CSV`, though is still new at this time. With Powershell less than 7, the suggestions are to read the file with `Get-Content`, remove double quotes and use `Set-Content`. Since the example content lacks double quotes, I decided to use `Get-Content`, split on commas and write with `Set-Content`.

The following code is a hybrid *batch-file* with *powershell* which I used as a basis to construct the previous code.
It has some comments that explains the code which is not suitable for inserting into a single powershell command.

```
<# :: Begin bat code

@echo off
setlocal

set "target=.\export.dat"
set "destination=.\updated.dat"

powershell -noprofile "invoke-expression(get-content '%~f0' | out-string)"

exit /b 0

#> ## Begin ps1 code

# Filepaths from environment variables.
$target = $env:target
$destination = $env:destination

# Read file content into a variable.
$content = get-content -literalpath $target

# Create an empty array for modified content.
$modifiedContent = @()

# Add 1st line as unmodified header.
$modifiedContent += $content[0]

# Add the rest of the lines.
foreach ($line in $content[1 .. ($content.length - 1)]) {

    # Require a leading capital D to modify a line.
    if ($line.startswith('D,')) {

        # Split by commas.
        $items = $line.split(',')

        # Modify item 14.
        if ($items.length -gt 14) {
            $items[14] += '0'
            $line = $items -join ','
        }
    }

    # Add line to array.
    $modifiedContent += $line
}

# Write modified content to destination file.
$modifiedContent | set-content -literalpath $destination
```

If suitable, the powershell code portion could be copied to a `.ps1` file and just replace `$target = $env:target` and `$destination = $env:destination` with  `$target = '.\export.dat'` and `$destination = '.\updated.dat'`.

Input export.dat:

> ```
> 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16
> D,1,2126,4372,T,125P,,255473730,person,n,person,19800320,07833,300.00,07833,300.00,078330
> D,1,2126,4372,T,125P,,255473730,person,n,person,19800320,07833,300.00
> d,1,2126,4372,T,125P,,255473730,person,n,person,19800320,07833,300.00,07833,300.00,078330
> ```

Output updated.dat:

> ```
> 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16
> D,1,2126,4372,T,125P,,255473730,person,n,person,19800320,07833,300.00,078330,300.00,078330
> D,1,2126,4372,T,125P,,255473730,person,n,person,19800320,07833,300.00
> d,1,2126,4372,T,125P,,255473730,person,n,person,19800320,07833,300.00,07833,300.00,078330
> ```

- 1st line is the header unmodified.
- 2nd line is modified.
- 3rd line is too short in length to modify.
- 4th line does not start with `D,` as `d,` does not match same case so is not modified.